# POSTGRESQL: Can you set a path which psql uses for finding SQL files when executing command from file?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm coming from an Oracle background and was used to setting an environment variable called SQLPATH which works pretty much like the $PATH on Linux.

To my understanding, when using the "\i" for executing a SQL file there are 3 options for supplying the filename (with or without path)

1. if the sql file is in the directory where psql was started, you can just use the filename ( without path )
2. you can use the fully qualified path for the script
3. you could use the tilde symbol as part of the path ( eg. ~/myscripts/script1.sql )

After some research, I found another option that is pretty close to what I was looking for

4. provide a variable on psql start that holds a directory ( where you could store your scripts )

   psql -p 5433 -v sqlpath="/tmp" database2

In this case /tmp was used as directory.
Inside psql you can now use the variable as reference to the directory

```
    databse2=# \i :sqlpath/current_time.sql
       current_timestamp
-------------------------------
 2023-03-04 10:51:35.156136+01
(1 row)
```

So this is close to what can be achieved in Oracle by using SQLPATH.

Are any additional/better options ?

Comment: Why not just change the current working directory to the desired location?  Either before starting psql, or by using `\cd` from within it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this information, and I will consider this. Unfortunately the `\cd` is not repecting the tilde - see example `xxx2=# \i ~/myscripts/recreate_t1.sql
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 10
xxx2=# \cd ~/myscripts/
create_t1.sql    fill_t1.sql      recreate_t1.sql  test.sql
xxx2=# \cd ~/myscripts/
\cd: could not change directory to "~/myscripts/": No such file or directory
`

Comment: Instead of `~`, you could use ` `echo ~` ` (including the backticks).